# Fetch the IP address of the device the app is running on - React Native

Tags: react-native, server, ip

I ran a node server with routes. But to fetch the data, we use the IP address of the device it's running on. Like, `fetch ('http://127.0.0.1/query')`.

Is there a way to fetch the `IP` address of the device in a react native app for this purpose? Or any other efficient way to fetch the data from the server?

Comment: Do you mean `localhost` ??

Comment: Ohh, sorry. It was my misunderstanding of the concept. Got it. Thanks.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, would you please select my answer and close the question?

Answer (score 0):

App device addresses mean themselves. it is `localhost`.